# UnicodeDecodeError: in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, encoding

I am working with the VirusTotal api, exactly with this: 
https://www.virustotal.com/es/documentation/public-api/#scanning-files

This is the part of my scritp where im having problems:

```
def scanAFile(fileToScan):
    host = "www.virustotal.com"
    selector = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan"
    fields = [("apikey", myPublicKey)]
    file_to_send = open(fileToScan, "rb").read()
    files = [("file", fileToScan, file_to_send)]
    json = postfile.post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files)

    return simplejson.loads(json)
```

With some files there is not any error and it runs fine, but the next error is occurring when trying to scan some files, for example this error is for a jpg file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/devPy/myProjects/script_vt.py", line 138, in <module>
    scanMyFile()
  File "F:/devPy/myProjects/script_vt.py", line 75, in scanQueue
    jsonScan = scanAFile(fileToScan)
  File "F:/devPy/myProjects/script_vt.py", line 37, in scanAFile
    json = postfile.post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files)
  File "F:\devPy\myProjects\script_vt.py", line 10, in post_multipart
    content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files)
  File "F:\devPy\myProjects\script_vt.py", line 42, in encode_multipart_formdata
    body = CRLF.join(L)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I should indicate I work with pycharm under windows, could this cause the encoding error?

Any idea how to solve it? I got stack and couldnt find any solution on the net.