# VirusTotal error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python

I have a python 2.7 script which uses VirusTotal Api 2.0 (more info: https://www.virustotal.com/es/documentation/public-api/#scanning-files ) When I try to scan some files it works without problems sometimes, but others it raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/devPy/myProjects/script_vt.py", line 138, in <module>
    scanMyFile()
  File "F:/devPy/myProjects/script_vt.py", line 75, in scanQueue
    jsonScan = scanAFile(fileToScan)
  File "F:/devPy/myProjects/script_vt.py", line 37, in scanAFile
    json = postfile.post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files)
  File "F:\devPy\myProjects\script_vt.py", line 10, in post_multipart
    content_type, body = encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files)
  File "F:\devPy\myProjects\script_vt.py", line 42, in encode_multipart_formdata
    body = CRLF.join(L)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is where the error is raised.:

```
def scanAFile(fileToScan):
    host = "www.virustotal.com"
    selector = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan"
    fields = [("apikey", myPublicKey)]
    file_to_send = open(fileToScan, "rb").read()
    files = [("file", fileToScan, file_to_send)]
    json = postfile.post_multipart(host, selector, fields, files)

    return simplejson.loads(json)
```

I read a lot of similar questions on StackOverflow but none of them worked for me.
I use pycharm under Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: in python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329477/unicodedecodeerror-in-python-2-7)

Comment: You are asking the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329477/unicodedecodeerror-in-python-2-7), please, do not flood

Comment: Sorry, Yes it is the same question but still after one month have the same problem and noone answered, should I delete the new or old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem is due to unicode code data. Setting the default encoding as UTF-8 may fix the issue.

Add the below lines in the top of the script.

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: I already tried this, the new error message is:   File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte